# Using the Google Cloud Vision API with a simple API key

Tags: java, google-api, api-key, google-cloud-vision

I am using the Google Cloud Vision Java API client documented here: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/libraries.

The following quickstart code works fine if I use the implicit default credentials by setting the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable to reference a json file for the right "service account".

```
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
import com.google.cloud.vision.spi.v1.ImageAnnotatorClient;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.AnnotateImageRequest;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.AnnotateImageResponse;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.BatchAnnotateImagesResponse;

...


public class QuickstartSample {
  public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    // Instantiates a client
    ImageAnnotatorClient vision = ImageAnnotatorClient.create();

    ...

    BatchAnnotateImagesResponse response = vision.batchAnnotateImages(requests);
    List<AnnotateImageResponse> responses = response.getResponsesList();

    ...
  }
}
```

However, I want to authenticate to the API using a simple (single-string) API key rather than a service account, and I cannot find documentation explaining how to do that through this java library.  Is it possible?

Comment: same problem here, did you found a solution?

Comment: @JohnnyAW:  I don't think it can be done.  My work-around has been to use the REST API (https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate) instead of the RPC API.  It's not so hard to build the JSON fragments using a StringBuilder and then parse the response using GSON or whatever.

Comment: I'm also looking for this. Is strange that it's so simple using REST calls but not with the Java library.

Comment: maybe this might help: it's a code sample for Android (which uses Java), and uses a simple API key: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-vision/tree/master/android

Answer (score 0):

It's possible: Create an ImageAnnotatorSettings like:

```
ImageAnnotatorSettings ias = ImageAnnotatorSettings.newBuilder()
        .setCredentialsProvider(
                FixedCredentialsProvider.create(#InputStream of your json key#)
        )
        .build();
```

replace your line

```
ImageAnnotatorClient vision = ImageAnnotatorClient.create();
```

with

```
ImageAnnotatorClient vision = ImageAnnotatorClient.create(ias);
```

Give it a try!

Comment: Unfortunately, this code no longer works with the latest version e.g. newBuilder() no longer exists

Comment: Not possible anymore according to https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/issues/3763